# Display JSON object in DIV using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong here? I am retrieving a JSON object using ESPN API, however I am unable to make it display in a DIV on my HTML page.

**My jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: " ",
    url: 'http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/16?enable=stats,leaders&seasontype=2&_accept=text/json&apikey=XXXXX2457896',
    success: function(data) {
      $('#result').html(data);
      console.log('Load was performed.');
    }
});
```

**My Returned JSON**

```
{
  "sports": [
    {
      "name": "basketball",
      "id": 40,
      "leagues": [
        {
          "id": 46,
          "groupId": 7,
          "name": "National Basketball Assoc.",
          "abbreviation": "NBA",
          "teams": [
            {
              "id": 16,
              "location": "Minnesota",
              "name": "Timberwolves",
              "abbreviation": "MIN",
              "color": "0E3764",
              "links": {
                "api": {
                  "teams": {
                    "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/16"
                  },
                  "news": {
                    "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/16/news"
                  },
                  "notes": {
                    "href": "http://api.espn.com/v1/sports/basketball/nba/teams/16/news/notes"
                  }
                },
                "web": {
                  "teams": {
                    "href": "http://espn.go.com/nba/team/_/name/min/minnesota-timberwolves?ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                  }
                },
                "mobile": {
                  "teams": {
                    "href": "http://m.espn.go.com/nba/clubhouse?teamId=16&ex_cid=espnapi_public"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "resultsOffset": 0,
  "resultsLimit": 50,
  "resultsCount": 1,
  "timestamp": "2012-07-03T16:33:07Z",
  "status": "success"
}
```

The request works fine and everything. I just can't figure out how to get the data to appear on my HTML page.I thought I could just use the `.html()` property, but I must be missing something.

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Do you want to output it just to prove it's there, or do you want to literally see a JSON object? Or do you want it nicely formatted for some sort of statistics page or fan page widget? What is the end product meant to be?

Comment: @Greg Pettit.. End goal would make it nicely formatted. The product is meant to be a sports app. So basically I want to be able to display the data in a usable manor.Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9PGhg/3/).

Look at the bottom of the JavaScript where I get the JSON. Then I use dot notation to traverse the object and get the information I need and output it:

`data.sports[0].leagues[0].teams[0].links.api` this is the sort of thing you will need to do

```
$.getJSON('/sports', function(data) {

    var links = data.sports[0].leagues[0].teams[0].links.api

    for(var key in links) {

        $('body').append('<a href="'+ links[key].href +'">'+ links[key].href +'</a><br />');          

    }                 

});
```

the `[0]` is used because you have used arrays in your JSON.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap the json in a `<pre></pre>` block and then output that onto the page

Comment: If that works at all (haven't tried it, but let's say it does), it will just show the big JSON-formatted string. I suspect Kris wants human-formatted output.

Comment: He said he wanted to have the data appear on the page. If he wants it formatted he could use the `data.sports` to get access to the json data and output any of the properties he wants

Comment: @jamcoupe Yes, exactly. I just asked instead of making assumptions (whoops!) but I admit, my assumption is that they want to have nice-looking output of the information found within data.sports and just doesn't know how to build an iterator to loop over it and grab those parts. Could be a bad assumption.

Comment: @jamcoupe .. Could you give me an example of how to do the data.sports .. Thanks...

Comment: @KrisHollenbeck I have added a new answer with giving you an example of how to use dot notation on a json object

Comment: @jamcoupe I was away for a bit for lunch... I will take a look at it now

Comment: appending JSON.stringify(jsonObject, null, 5) to some <pre></pre> tag outputs a readable represantation of the JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

`data.sports[0].leagues[0].teams[0].links.api`

this is the sort of thing you will need to do

```
$.getJSON('/sports', function(data) {

    var links = data.sports[0].leagues[0].teams[0].links.api

    for(var key in links) {

        $('body').append('<a href="'+ links[key].href +'">'+ links[key].href +'</a><br />');          

    }
}
```