# Android Facebook SDK parsing JSON

Tags: android, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I Have problem with parsing JSON code . I am working with Facebook SDK on Android. have seen many tutorials, but they don't help me.

```
{
  "id": "1000004577",
  "friends": {
   "data": [
  {
    "id": "11343",
    "statuses": {
      "data": [
        {
          "from": {
            "name": "Maria",
            "id": "1134"
          },
          "message": "...How wonderfull life ",
          "updated_time": "2011-07-05T21:42:29+0000",
          "id": "18665783"
        },
        {
          "from": {
            "name": "Maria ",
            "id": "113931"
          },
          "message": "Ab Montag geht es wieder um 8 Uhr los!\nWir werden jetzt ein Woche vom Herrn Vollrerrichtetitet die N wie möglich!!!\n\nIm auftrag von:\n\n Herrn Siebert",
          "updated_time": "2010-10-01T18:05:59+0000",
          "id": "158583"
        },
        {
          "from": {
            "name": "Maria",
            "id": "11343"
          },
          "message": "Esmu majas...!!! viss ir labi!!!",
          "updated_time": "2010-07-16T08:04:36+0000",
          "id": "137470438"
        },
        {
          "from": {
            "name": "Maria ",
            "id": "113421"
          },
          "message": "I miss kitkat ice-cream!:(",
          "updated_time": "2010-06-06T16:46:13+0000",
          "id": "10231545"
        },
        {
          "from": {
            "name": "Maria",
            "id": "113121"
          },
          "message": "its snowin..xD or it looks like!!!!",
          "updated_time": "2010-06-02T12:57:39+0000",
          "id": "12623356466"
        }
      ],
      "paging": {
        "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/1134393121/statuses?limit=5&fields=from,message,updated_time&since=1309902149&__paging_token=1866653502783",
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/1134393121/statuses?limit=5&fields=from,message,updated_time&until=1275483459&__paging_token=126233544066466"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "1179089",
    "statuses": {
      "data": [
        {
          "from": {
            "name": "Kristine Vaidere",
            "id": "123089"
          },
          "message": "Запомни! Если ты отключаешь мозги, то ты обязательно должна включить телефон. Что-то из этого должно работать всегда. :D",
          "updated_time": "2013-07-31T08:43:12+0000",
          "id": "1020030233771"
        },
        {
          "from": {
            "name": "Kristine",
            "id": "1179239"
          },
          "message": "bija ideāls! Paldies Prāta vētrai un maniem mīļ",
          "updated_time": "2013-06-09T15:20:50+0000",
          "id": "10200519756813"
        },
        {
          "from": {
            "name": "Kristine ",
            "id": "1179089"
          },
          "message": "Mīļie, takā es pazaudēju savu telefonu :( , man nomainijās nr. Lūdzu sūtiet man savējos un esējo :*",
          "updated_time": "2013-05-07T19:50:00+0000",
          "id": "121433892"
        },
        {
          "from": {
            "name": "Kristine",
            "id": "1179589"
          },
          "message": "nepacietīgs pūlis\n brēc, un rokām plātās baigi.\n jo katrs jau zin kā labāk vaj’g",
          "updated_time": "2013-02-01T14:40:26+0000",
          "id": "463167214"
        },
        {
          "from": {
            "name": "Kristine",
            "id": "11523089"
          },
          "message": "Manas jūtas pret dažiem cilvēkiem nav iespējams izteikt vārdos.. Tās var izteikt tikai ar lāpstu, cirvi vai kaut ko tamlīdzīgu... :D",
          "updated_time": "2013-01-17T21:31:59+0000",
          "id": "454819157"
        }
      ],
      "paging": {
        "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/1179523089/statuses?limit=5&fields=from,message,updated_time&since=1375260192&__paging_token=10200845330233771",
        "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/1179523089/statuses?limit=5&fields=from,message,updated_time&until=1358458319&__paging_token=4548195341157"
      }
    }
  }
],
"paging": {
  "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/100000425773779/friends?limit=2&fields=statuses.limit(5).fields(from,message,updated_time)&offset=2&__after_id=1179523089"
}
}
}
```

I need to get these values:

```
             "from": {
                 "name": "Maria ",
                 "id": "113421"
              },
                 "message": "I miss kitkat ice-cream!:(",
                 "updated_time": "2010-06-06T16:46:13+0000",
                 "id": "10231545"
```

And then store them in the hashmap... It would be great if someone would help whit this
Here is the pice of code that not work properly.

```
package com.androidhive.jsonparsing;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;

 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import com.androidhive.jsonparsing.R;
 import com.androidhive.jsonparsing.R.id;
  import com.androidhive.jsonparsing.R.layout;

 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
 import android.widget.ListAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
 import android.widget.TextView;

 public class AndroidJSONParsingActivity extends ListActivity {




// url to make request
private static String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/100000425773779?fields=friends.limit(1).fields(statuses.limit(5).fields(from,message,updated_time))?access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAJvWFqIXsQXvJvN7mZBHDn6g3ocW4HvfKZCl8JfSkeDvdQNVnVO0UyM297pcM1SlecH613j4NT1KZBCZAAG7L4hTMY7yhZCQRLwhYzHCM6zZAi3ZCwA48JXoJH31QInRO5hjWTyTFEHVL8ao7CRJVc4OLZAooqTQlgZDZD";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_GDATA = "data";
private static final String TAG_DATA = "data";
private static final String TAG_STATUSES = "statuses";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
private static final String TAG_FROM = "from";
private static final String TAG_UPDATE = "updated_time";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_FRIENDS = "friends";
private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";


// contacts JSONArray
JSONArray contacts = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Hashmap for ListView
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    // Creating JSON Parser instance
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // getting JSON string from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);


    //Here starts the MESS
    try {
        // Getting Array of Contacts
        JSONObject arrfriends = json.getJSONObject(TAG_FRIENDS);
        JSONObject genData = arrfriends.getJSONObject(TAG_GDATA);

        JSONArray generalData = ;

        for(int i=0; i < contacts.length(); i++) { // Loop over each each row
            JSONObject row = contacts.getJSONObject(i); // Get row object
            JSONObject c = row.getJSONObject(TAG_DATA);

            for(int j=0; j < c.length(); j++){                              

                JSONObject from = c.getJSONObject(TAG_FROM);
                String name = from.getString(TAG_NAME);
                String id = from.getString(TAG_ID);
                String message = c.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                String update = c.getString(TAG_UPDATE);
                String mId = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                // creating new HashMap

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value

                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                map.put(TAG_MESSAGE, message);
                map.put(TAG_UPDATE, update);
                map.put(TAG_ID, mId);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                contactList.add(map);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    /**
     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
     * */
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, contactList,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_MESSAGE, TAG_UPDATE }, new int[] {
                    R.id.name, R.id.email, R.id.mobile });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.email)).getText().toString();
            String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mobile)).getText().toString();

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_MESSAGE, cost);
            in.putExtra(TAG_UPDATE, description);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });



}

}
```

Comment: plese refer the link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11315407/display-json-object-in-div-using-jquery

Comment: It's not Android programming language

Answer (score 2):

Please use GSON https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ , It will convert your JSON to Java object and from Java object you can easily get whatever property you need.

Answer (score 0):

The following code illustrates how you can parse this jsonResponse. The code to save it in a hashmap is not written, you can do it yourself easily if you understand the parsing.

```
JSONObject job = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
String friendResponse = job.optString("friends");

//Now friendResponse is also a JSONObject
JSONObject friendResponse = new JSONObject(friendResponse);
String data = friendResponse.optString("data");

//Now...data is a JSONArray

JSONArray jar = new JSONArray(data);
for(int i=0;i<jar.size();i++){
    String friendsDataJson = jar.getString(i);
    //Handle the values here... you may have to make more JSONObjects to parse. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should be clear about JSON objects and JSON Arrays. Refer to this [article](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/) and similar queries on stackoverflow for details.

In your case, you are not getting data array correctly, instead of

```
 JSONObject arrfriends = json.getJSONObject(TAG_FRIENDS);
    JSONObject genData = arrfriends.getJSONObject(TAG_GDATA);
```

it should be

```
 JSONObject arrfriends = json.getJSONObject(TAG_FRIENDS);
    JSONObject genData = arrfriends.getJSONArray(TAG_GDATA);
```

then you can iterate over the genData array like this

```
for ( int i=0;i<genData.length();i++)
{
JSONObject contact=genData.getJSONObject(i);

}
```

same logic has to be applied for further parsing with in json.

Comment: JSONObject arrfriends = json.getJSONObject(TAG_FRIENDS); gives me an error : ord.json.JSONException: no value for friends.

Comment: System.out.println(json.toString()); gives me :
{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","code:104}}

Comment: you are making some other mistake. Last message indicates that your session is not valid or in other words you do not have an access token. This means that you are not getting json at all.

Comment: yeah, thanks, I underestood that :) will try to find information about that.